# Add attributes to a builtin class in Python? (For detecting win in tic tac toe)

Tags: python, loops, class, pygame, attributes

I am writing a tic tac toe game in Python with Pygame. I need to check in my loop if there are any winners (3 in a row or diagonally). I draw naughts and crosses using a for loop and positions of rectangles (builtin class in Pygame).

Is it possible to make my own attribute to a builtin class (pygame.rect), for example...

```
sq1.isFull = True
```

...even though that isn't a builtin method of rect?

If not, how would I go about checking for wins, if all of my squares and circles are made in a for loop?

Code shown below:

```
import pygame

# initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# window setup
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((550, 550))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tic Tac Toe by Donnaven')

# squares
sq1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (25, 25, 150, 150))
sq2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (200, 25, 150, 150))
sq3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (375, 25, 150, 150))

sq4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (25, 200, 150, 150))
sq5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (200, 200, 150, 150))
sq6 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (375, 200, 150, 150))

sq7 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (25, 375, 150, 150))
sq8 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (200, 375, 150, 150))
sq9 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (375, 375, 150, 150))

square_list = [sq1, sq2, sq3, sq4, sq5, sq6, sq7, sq8, sq9]

# game loop
pTurn = True  # Whose turn it is.
# True = Rectangle, False = Circle
running = True

while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    # checking for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            for square in square_list:
                if square.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    square_x = square.x
                    square_y = square.y

                    # draw shape inside of square
                    if pTurn:  # rectangle player turn
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (square_x + 25, square_y + 25, 100, 100))
                        pTurn = False
                    elif not pTurn:  # circle player turn
                        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), (square_x + 75, square_y + 75), 60)
                        pTurn = True

    # update frame (DONE LAST!)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can create a wrapper class, a-la composition.

```py
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, square):
        self.square = square
        self.is_full = False

square_list = [Tile(sq1), ... Tile(sqn)]

for tile in square_list:
    square = tile.square
    if square.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and not tile.is_full:
        ...
        tile.is_full = True
```

Or take a look at the answer by @Rabbid76 for inheritance. Many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: I will try this once I get time, thank you. But, I see the term 'wrapper' used frequently. What does it mean?

Comment: Here I'm using it as a catch-all term for a class used in place of the contained object. Just one level of abstraction away from the "real thing."

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. I will implement this soon! I will make sure to mark it as answer once I finish. Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem! Take another look at @Rabbid76's answer as well, showcases good style, might lead to cleaner code in the long run.

Comment: I modified the code as you
recommended, but now it only shows
if circles: Here's the code:
https://pastebin.com/YMeDyjnz

Comment: If the code in that link is the code in its entirety, then first thing - you still need to initialize the sq1, sq2, ... sq9 like you did previously. Eventually you might want to refactor it to render them programatically so you don't need to copy+paste essentially the same line 9 times, but one step at a time.

Comment: Also, in your range (`for Tile in square_list:`,  line 30) don't use capital "T" for your tile object, I'm not sure what that could lead to, if that's considered shadowing an object type.  May not do anything bad now, but it might eventually lead to some nasty side effects. The `x` in `for x in y:` should never be an object type, it's just an instance of the next object found in the `y` iterable.

Comment: No, the code in that link isn't in its' entirety. If you wish for the full code here it is: https://pastebin.com/ptFNNhF1. I made the modifications you suggested, but now whenever I click it only shows 1 kind of shape (either all circle or all rectangle). I'm making sure to change pTurn everytime someone makes a move, I don't understand why it only shows 1 shape. Do you know what may be the problem?

Comment: just saw the issue: you're setting `pTurn` in the `if, elif` instead of your refactored `p_turn`. Typos, nasty little buggers! :)

Comment: AAAH that was such a stupid issue!! can't believe I couldn't find a typo.. thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an attribute to the class use [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance). Create a class `MyRect` with subclass `pygame.Rect`:

```py
class MyRect(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, isFull = True):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.isFull = isFull
```

However, you should also consider creating a class for a tile that aggregates a `pygame.Rect`:

```py
class MyTile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, isFull = True):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.isFull = isFull
```

This would allow you to make `MyTile` a subclass of [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite):

```py
class MyTile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, isFull = True):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.isFull = isFull
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0)) # just for example
```